# CK Editor breaking image paths that use breakpoints

Tags: ckeditor

On page save the image paths are modified which is causing the image path to fail. There should be a \ between _webedit and cached-images and the \ with first digit of the image file name is being modified.

How can I prevent this and which files do I need to modify?

**Input**

```
    <img src="http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-
    0-617-10000-7488-767.jpg" 
    srcset="http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-
    617-10000-7488-1920.jpg 
    1920w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-
    617-10000-7488-256.jpg 
    256w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-512.jpg 
    512w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-768.jpg 
    768w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-1024.jpg 
    1024w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-
    617-10000-7488-1280.jpg 
    1280w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-
    617-10000-7488-1536.jpg 
    1536w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-
    617-10000-7488-1792.jpg 
    1792w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-
    617-10000-7488-566.jpg 
    566w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-1132.jpg 
    1132w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webedit\cached-images\21-0-0-
    617-10000-7488-1698.jpg 1698w" sizes="(max-width:383px) 100vw,(min-
    width:384px) and (max-width:575px) 100vw,(min-width:576px) and (max-
    width:767px) 100vw,(min-width:768px) and (max-width:959px) calc(50.26vw 
    - 12px),(min-width:960px) and (max-width:1152px) calc(50vw - 
    10px),566px" alt="Soak up the sun in our relaxing garden" data-aspect-
    ratio="0.5000">
```

**Output**

```
    <img alt="Soak up the sun in our relaxing garden" data-aspect-        
    ratio="0.5000" sizes="(max-width:383px) 100vw,(min-width:384px) and 
    (max-width:575px) 100vw,(min-width:576px) and (max-width:767px) 100vw,
    (min-width:768px) and (max-width:959px) calc(50.26vw - 12px),(min-
    width:960px) and (max-width:1152px) calc(50vw - 10px),566px" 
    src="http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-767.jpg" 
    srcset="http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-1920.jpg 
    1920w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-256.jpg 256w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-
    images-0-0-617-10000-7488-512.jpg 
    512w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-768.jpg 768w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-
    images-0-0-617-10000-7488-1024.jpg 
    1024w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-1280.jpg 
    1280w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-1536.jpg 
    1536w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-1792.jpg 
    1792w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-566.jpg 566w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-
    images-0-0-617-10000-7488-1132.jpg 
    1132w,http://www.domain.co.uk/_webeditcached-images-0-0-617-
    10000-7488-1698.jpg 1698w" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is a special character in many coding stuff indicating special treatment for the next character. Thus the editor is trying to interpret `\c` and that results in just a `c`.

If `\` is just because you're using folder notation for Windows, `/` should work fine instead, and what is commonly used. If this fails you can force a backslash by adding a `\` to every single one. Thus

```
_webedit\\cached
```

and `\\` will interpret as `\`. I'm pretty sure though `/` will work and is much more advised.

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is JavaScript application and has no influence on saving data. If you can switch to `Source` mode and back without URL being changed then this is not editor fault and you need to look for the problem in your server-side code.